# Model existence theorem for Logics

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

- Any consistent first order theory $T$ has a model.
- For a second order theory this is false.
- Even for geometric theories this is false.

  But what is the state of art in this subject, can we somehow characterize logics for which there is a model?

This question is somehow located in a framework of [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269512/geometric-theories-have-models-in-any-grothendieck-topos) I am asking in these days.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838284/which-second-order-theories-have-a-model